# Saving a command into a variable instead of running it

Tags: linux, bash, variables, ps

I'm trying to get the output of the ps command to output to a file, then to use that file to populate a radiolist. So far I'm having problems.

```
eval "ps -o pid,command">/tmp/process$$
more /tmp/process$$
sed -e '1d' /tmp/process$$ > /tmp/process2$$
    while IFS= read -r pid command
    do
        msgboxlist="$msgboxlist" $($pid) $($command) "off"
    done</tmp/process2$$
    height=`wc -l "/tmp/process$$" | awk '{print $1}'`
    width=`wc --max-line-length "/tmp/process$$" | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo $height $width
    dialog \
        --title "Directory Listing" \
        --radiolist "Select process to terminate" "$msgboxlist" $(($height+7)) $(($width+4))
```

So far not only does the while read not split the columns into 2 variables (`$pid` is the whole line and `$command` is blank) but when I try to run this the script is trying to run the line as a command. For example:

```
+ read -r pid command
++ 7934 bash -x assessment.ba
assessment.ba: line 322: 7934: command not found
+ msgboxlist=
+ off
assessment.ba: line 322: off: command not found
```

Basically I have no idea where I'm supposed to be putting quotes, double quotes and backslashes. It's driving me wild.

tl;dr Saving a command into a variable without running it, how?

Comment: [Please](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) [consider](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) what you're [doing](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html). That code is scary! You might want to post on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute `$pid` and `$command` as commands:

```
msgboxlist="$msgboxlist" $($pid) $($command) "off"
```

Try:

```
msgboxlist="$msgboxlist $pid $command off"
```

Or use an array:

```
msgboxlist=()  # do this before the while loop
msgboxlist+=($pid $command "off")

# when you need to use the whole list:
echo "${msgboxlist[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script can be refactored by removing some unnecessary calls like this:

```
ps -o pid=,command= > /tmp/process$$
msgboxlist=""
while read -r pid command
do
    msgboxlist="$msgboxlist $pid $command off"
done < /tmp/process2$$

height=$(awk 'END {print NR}' "/tmp/process$$")

width=$(awk '{if (l<length($0)) l=length($0)} END{print l}' "/tmp/process$$")

dialog --title "Directory Listing" \
    --radiolist "Select process to terminate" "$msgboxlist" $(($height+7)) $(($width+4))
```

Comment: Nice refactoring.  I can actually understand the intent now.  :-)  Also, the `width=` line can be shortened a little bit using: `awk 'length($0)>l{l=length($0)}END{print l}'`

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I'm not 100% clear on what you're doing; but I think you want to change this:

```
        msgboxlist="$msgboxlist" $($pid) $($command) "off"
```

to this:

```
        msgboxlist+=("$pid" "$command" off)
```

which will add the PID, the command, and "off" as three new elements to the array named `msgboxlist`. You'd then change `"$msgboxlist"` to `"${msgboxlist[@]}"` in the `dialog` command, to include all of those elements as arguments to the command.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes when you want variables to be expanded. Use single quotes to disable variable expansion.

Here's an example of a command saved for later execution.

```
file="readme.txt"
cmd="ls $file" # $file is expanded to readme.txt
echo "$cmd" # ls readme.txt
$cmd # lists readme.txt
```

Edit adressing the read:

Using read generally reads an entire line. Consider this instead (tested):

```
ps o pid=,command= | while read line ; do 
  set $line
  pid=$1
  command=$2 
  echo $pid $command
done
```

Also note the different usage of 'ps o pid=,command=' to skip displaying headers.

Comment: No need for `eval $cmd`, `$cmd` expands just fine and runs the command.